# String finder function

Tags: c++, beginner, strings

This function finds a certain string within a string. I feel like my function is too messy.

I'm new to C memory functions. Are there any shortcuts I can take to make this function shorter? Is this implementation effective?

```
bool strfound(char * find, char * name) {
    int j = 0;
    int size = strlen(name) + 1;
    char * buffer;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(size + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        if (i == 0 && name[i] != ' ') {
            j++;
            buffer[j - 1] = name[0];
        }
        if (i != 0 && name[i] != ' ') {
            buffer[j] = name[i];
            j++;
        }

        if (name[i] == ' ' || i == size - 1) {
            buffer[j] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(buffer, find) == 0) {
                std::cout << "String is found: " << buffer << std::endl;
                buffer[j] = '\0';
                std::cout << name << std::endl;
                free(buffer);
                return true;
            }
            strcpy(buffer, ""); // or null from 0
            buffer = (char*)malloc(size + 1);
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output: https://gyazo.com/2fc0fe88958dfeb2f8cf20eff1f2d113

Comment: Is it C or C++? Please, keep only one of those tags. They're different languages.

Comment: This code is difficult to judge. It is not valid C code, because of the use of `std::cout`, yet it is not idiomatic C++ either, since it uses so many C functions. Did you write this code as an exercise, or are you unaware or `strstr()`?

Comment: That code might leak memory.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel of the existing string finding routines?

Comment: `"Is this implementation effective?"` If not it would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your primary question is yes, methods already exist in libraries that can do this. Reference [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c).

Your method can then be simplified to what's shown below:

```
#include <string>

bool strfound(const std::string &in, const std::string &substr) {
    return in.find(substr) != std::string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to use the `&` after the types of the params to indicate pass-by-reference? I know the whole string won't get copied due to `std::string` having copy-on-write, but pass-by-value still creates another object unnecessarily.

Comment: @Snowbody Yes, that would be optimal. Honestly just slipped my mind at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to reinvent the wheel here.

```
bool strfound(char * find, char * name) {
```

If you are writing for C++, you should be using the `std::string` type everywhere -- it's much better than `char *`. It handles allocation and deallocation automatically. The length is kept for you.

```
    int j = 0;
    int size = strlen(name) + 1;
    char * buffer;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(size + 1);
```

If you are writing for C++, and need to allocate dynamic memory you should be using the C++ memory allocation operators `new` and `delete`. The reason is that `malloc()` is not type-safe. Note that C++ is giving you an error preventing you from using `malloc()` without the typecast.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

The first time this code runs, `buffer` has been allocated, but not initialized. You'll get the default values from the `malloc()` (or hopefully the `new`). That's probably not what you want.

It is also not a good idea to use `std::endl` as a matter of course. That forces a buffer flush. This is of no value unless you expect your program to crash, which is a bad thing to be planning for. Nearly all the time you should just use `"\n"` and let the library decide when to flush the buffer.

Anyway. Is this output part of the normal course of action of the routine, or is it just for debugging purposes? Generally you shouldn't mix program logic and user interaction.

```
        if (i == 0 && name[i] != ' ') {
            j++;
            buffer[j - 1] = name[0];
        }
        if (i != 0 && name[i] != ' ') {
            buffer[j] = name[i];
            j++;
        }
```

These two sections are mutually exclusive (if one is taken the other will not be); perhaps a better code arrangement is possible.

```
        if (name[i] == ' ' || i == size - 1) {
```

Better to use `isspace(name[i])` here instead of just the literal `' '` as there are several different spaces there could be.

```
            buffer[j] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(buffer, find) == 0) {
                std::cout << "String is found: " << buffer << std::endl;
```

Similar warnings hear to the other output, though at least `buffer` will have data in it at this point.

```
                buffer[j] = '\0';
```

You just did this three lines up.

```
                std::cout << name << std::endl;
```

And again.

```
            strcpy(buffer, ""); // or null from 0
```

This is not the right way to clear out `buffer`. Just set the first item to `'\0'`.

```
            buffer = (char*)malloc(size + 1);
```

Why are you re-allocating `buffer` here? What's wrong with the old one? This is a memory leak.

Comment: Another reason to prefer `new` over `malloc()` is that the code isn't checking for a `NULL` return...

Answer (score -1):

Quick function I wrote up that might help, tested it twice so it should work:

```
//Returns 0 for succes and 1 for failiure
int strfound(const char *string, const char *name) {
    int stringSize = strlen(string);
    int nameSize = strlen(name);

    if (nameSize > stringSize || nameSize <= 0) {
       return 1;
    }

    int foundChars = 0; //Number of the chars found in the scanned string

    for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++) {
        if (string[i] == name[foundChars]) { //Looks for match in string and name at indexes i and foundChars
           foundChars++;
           if (foundChars == nameSize) {
              return 0; //Succes
           }
        }
        else {
            foundChars = 0; //Reset the foundChars counter
        }
    }

    return 1; //Scanned whole string failiure
}
```

If you want the function to only find the words as their own words and not inside of another word, you can just check for a space one step back, before `foundChars` gets set to 1 (also check if it's the start of the string i.e. `i == 0`). For the end of the name (`foundChars == nameSize`) check for a space or end of string one step forward in string. Leave a comment on the answer if you want a more in depth/better explanation.

I think this method could work a lot better because you don't need to allocate any memory manually, and it's much more readable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why'd you change the return type from `bool` to `int` ? Even if it's supposed to be straight C, `bool` is legal from C99 on.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.